# why the mysql's result of docker search is zero

Tags: docker

I was learning docker recently.

When i executed this command `docker search mysql`

It returns:
[image]

I cound't understand why the image(mysql official version)'s stars is 0 but not 10K+.

Because I go to the docker GUI and search mysql,its show me 10K+.

Hope somebody can answer me,thx~

Comment: possible issue code: https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cli/command/registry/formatter_search.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in docker hub. 
The problem has been forwarded and the [issue](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/2212#issuecomment-1054275730) has been fixed.

```sh
$ docker search mysql
NAME                             DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
mysql                            MySQL is a widely used, open-source relation…   12182     [OK]
mariadb                          MariaDB Server is a high performing open sou…   4677      [OK]
mysql/mysql-server               Optimized MySQL Server Docker images. Create…   907                  [OK]
```